# How can I run multiple sets of pipe-linked commands in parallel?

Tags: windows, batch, pipe

I want to run several sets of tasks connected by pipes in parallel like so:

```
app1 "input_file_1" | app2 > "output_file_1"
app1 "input_file_2" | app2 > "output_file_2"
...
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve this? I was able to build up what I wanted via a series of commands like this but I suspect there may be a better way:

```
start "" /b /min cmd /c "app1 "input_file_1" | app2 > "output_file_1""
```

Bonus points if anyone can think of a method that would still work with arbitrary input / output paths - i.e. different names, different folders, spaces in paths etc.

Comment: Whenever things start to get complex in Windows batch, it is generally a good time to switch to PowerShell instead. In PS, `start-job` and `start-process` cmdlets are used for forking.

Comment: I don't think I have access to powershell in my current environment, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: As you have access to the command prompt, simply type `powershell`. If the prompt changes to something starting `PS`, you have access to it. You will want to have at least PS v2 to use the start-* cmdlets. Type `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` at the PS prompt to find out.